# How to add helpers functions to anti:modals in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

In Meteor I'm using the anti:modals package by @Hubert OG to create modals and overlays.

```
            Template.product.events({

                'click .__yellow': function(e, t) {
                    AntiModals.overlay('modal', {
                        modal: true,
                        overlayClass: 'yellow',
                    });
                },
            });
```

The click event loads a template file: 'modal'. This all works out of the box. Since it renders a template I hope/think it's possible to add helpers to the template.

Like so:

```
            Template.modal.helpers({
                products: function () {
                    return Products.find({});
                },
                image:function(){  
                    return productImages.findOne({'metadata.productId':this._id})
                }
            });
```

But this doesn't work. It doesn't run any errors it just doesn't render anything. But if I add these helpers to any other template it does work.

I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just gave a quick look at the package but looking at the way the package is build, which version of meteor it's build for and the that it's not maintained the last 8 months tells me this package is sorta out of date..

Maybe its better to find some other package which handles with modals or simply use a javascript plugin which like foundation's (I use that one and it works pretty solid) http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks Dennis. I'm working with foundation in my project. Reveal doesn't work out of the box so I turned to anti:modals. Did you manually configure reveal?

Comment: No problem, You can load foundation in multiple ways.. I prefer to use bower (meteor has a package for it) over atmosphere because the original authors normally maintains their bower versions but not the atmosphere versions. Bower basically loads the foundation.min.css and and the foundation.min.js automatically for, but you could also just put them in your meteor package. The part ur missing is probably  calling the method  "$(document).foundation();" after the layout template is renderd.. Templat.mainLayout.onRendered in my case.